# Entity Framework Code First One-To-One Relationship not setting FK

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

using EF 6.0.1

I've got two entities; Cart and Shopper (simplified for illustration) defined as:

```
public class Cart
{
     public int Id { get; set; } // PK
     public int ShopperId { get; set; }
     // Navigation Property
     public virtual Shopper Shopper { get; set; }
}

public class Shopper
{
     public int Id { get; set; } // PK
     public int CartId { get; set; }
     // Navigation Property
     public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
}
```

and the following mapping

CartMap:

```
this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
this.HasRequired(t => t.Shopper).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Cart);
```

and ShopperMap

```
this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
this.HasRequired(t => t.Cart).WithRequiredDependent(t => t.Shopper);
```

Seed Code

```
var cart = new Cart{ Shopper = new Shopper()};
context.Carts.Add(cart);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When I attempt to seed the database by constructing a new cart and new shopper, the new cart and shopper are persisted, but the cart data isn't updated with the new Shopper PK Value and the the Shopper isn't updated with the new Cart Id PK Value.

What am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind showing the Seed code?

Comment: `var cart = new Cart{ Shopper = new Shopper()}; ` and context.Carts.Add(cart) and context.SaveChanges()

Comment: I think that EF uses columns like `Shopper_Id`.